# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list Error - Creating HTML Javascript Function Call

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a sidebar by copying code and editing it.  I've moved the myclick function before sidebar, I've checked for missing {'s, I've tried various forms of 
html += [code] and I continually get this error.  When I try it with what I have below, I get

```
"<a href="javascript:myclick("Bareburger");">Bareburger</a><br><a href="javascript:myclick("Shake Shack");">Shake Shack</a><br>"
```

in the alert(html) which gives me "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input.  I have also tried switching the html line with

```
html += '<a href="javascript:myclick(' + uniquerestaurants[i] + ');">' + uniquerestaurants[i] + '</a><br>';
```

except this part gives me in the alert:

```
<a href="javascript:myclick(Bareburger);">Bareburger</a><br><a href="javascript:myclick(Shake Shack);">Shake Shack</a><br>
```

and this error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list ".  I'm completely stuck because I copied this html += line from something that works and made the appropriate changes and still have yet to get the call to myclick to work properly. I've run out of things to guess...please help.

Don't know if this matters, but I've also tried removing the semicolon in ');">' and changing the order of the functions, but neither helped.

```
function makeSidebar() {
  var html = "";
  restaurantsbytype = [];
  uniquerestaurants = [];
  //for all markers clicked, get the restaurant name and make it a unique array
  for (var i=0; i<markerarray.length; i++) {
    if (markerarray[i].getVisible()) {
      restaurantsbytype.push(markerarray[i].myname);
    }
  }
  uniquerestaurants = restaurantsbytype.unique();
  //for unique list of restaurant names, create href
  for (var i=0; i<uniquerestaurants.length; i++) {
     html += '<a href="javascript:myclick(' + '"' + uniquerestaurants[i] +'"' + ');">' +     uniquerestaurants[i] + '</a><br>';
  }
  alert(html);
  document.getElementById("side_bar").innerHTML = html ;
}

function myclick(name) {
      alert(name);

  for (var i=0; i<markerarray.length; i++) {
    if (markerarray[i].myname == name) {
      //make markers of selected category bounce for 2.5 seconds
      markerarray[i].setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
      stopAnimation(markerarray[i]);    
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be like `javascript:myclick('Bareburger')` -- quote the arguments.

Comment: Solution: Don't use in-line javascript at all... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
html += '<a href="javascript:myclick(' + "'" + uniquerestaurants[i] + "'" + ');">' + uniquerestaurants[i] + '</a><br>';
```

Comment: THANK YOU!!  works perfectly.  why does it work when you switch the single and double quotes...i thought they were interchangeable?

Comment: They are more or less interchangeable, but you can't nest them inside themselves.  `x = "alpha "bravo" charlie";` is a mess, but `x="alpha 'bravo' charlie";` and `x='alpha "bravo" charlie';` are both ok.

Comment: I've noticed that if my restaurant name has an apostrophe in it, clicking on the link doesn't do anything...is there an easy fix for this?